# bsnl 3g datacard installation

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I'm trying to install `mobile_partner` software in Ubuntu 12.04 .
my problem is that I can use my Huawei modem for accessing Internet through network manager.

But I cant use the mobile partner software in Linux.

I Tried to install the mobile partner software . Here are the step I followed .

1. Copy the Linux folder from data-card to home directory.
2. Switch to the root account.
3. Running the install script

But when I run the install script. I got following error ;

```
Local path is: /usr/local/Mobile_Partner

Installing Mobile Partner..../install: line 495: ./MobilePartner_distrib: No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file `./rt/lib/': No such file or directory
cp: cannot create regular file `./rt/lib/': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/rt/lib/fonts/fallback': No such file or directory
Installing Driver...

/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver
Usage: modinfo [-0][-F field][-k kernelversion][-b basedir]  module...
 Prints out the information about one or more module(s).
 If a fieldname is given, just print out that field (or nothing if not found).
 Otherwise, print all information out in a readable form
 If -0 is given, separate with nul, not newline.
 If -b is given, use an image of the module tree.
ERROR: Removing 'cdc_ether': No such file or directory
ERROR: Removing 'usbnet': No such file or directory
ERROR: Removing 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory
make -C src/ clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
rm -rf *.o *.ko *~ core* .dep* .*.d .*.cmd *.mod.c *.a *.s .*.flags .tmp_versions Module.symvers Modules.symvers *.order
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "clean" "/lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
rmmod -f hw_cdc_driver
ERROR: Removing 'hw_cdc_driver': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
make -C src/ modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "modules" "/lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/usb"
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/build SUBDIRS=/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: In function ‘rx_tlp_parse’:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:601:7: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c: At top level:
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c:1986:2: error: unknown field ‘ioctl’ specified in initializer
make[3]: *** [/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-39-generic'
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
#install -m 744 -c hw_cdc_driver.o /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/net
#depmod -a
#modprobe hw_cdc_driver
/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/add_header.sh  "install"
modprobe hw_cdc_driver
FATAL: Module hw_cdc_driver not found.
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/Mobile_Partner/driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src'
make: *** [install] Error 2

Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/build) to be all installed?
Now please enter any key to finish other installations.
```

After pressing key :

```
NDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used.
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc5.d
`/etc/rc5.d/S99runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
`/etc/rc5.d/K10runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc2.d
`/etc/rc2.d/S99runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
`/etc/rc2.d/K10runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc3.d
`/etc/rc3.d/S99runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
`/etc/rc3.d/K10runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
ADDRUNLEVEL=/etc/rc4.d
`/etc/rc4.d/S99runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
`/etc/rc4.d/K10runhwactivator' -> `/etc/init.d/runhwactivator'
cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/acpi/suspend.d/': Not a directory
chmod: cannot access `/etc/acpi/suspend.d/010-huawei-suspend.sh': No such file or directory
```

The output of `lsusb` command is following:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b159 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

I already installed Linux -header ,ndis from synaptic  but I'm still stuck.

I don't know what to do please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Before install, you should give the `install` script, the Executable permission with,

```
sudo chmod +x install
```

Even there isn't `ndiswrapper` not install you can use that application.

You can install the same application which is from Ubuntu from this question:

[In Ubuntu, Is there an application like "Huawei Mobile Partner" for Broadband Connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380650/in-ubuntu-is-there-an-application-like-huawei-mobile-partner-for-broadband-co)