# In Ubuntu, is there an application like "Huawei Mobile Partner" for broadband dongle modems?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

Is there an application in Ubuntu which is like *Huawei Mobile Partner*, i. e. an application to manage broadband USB dongle modems? The application should provide:

1. Display bandwidth
2. SMS facility
3. Make Connection and Disconnection
4. Show Used Data Volume per given period

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Modem Manager GUI

**modem-manager-gui** is a complete solution to manage and monitor mobile network based modems. Some of its features include:

- In addition to Display Bandwidth and SMS, it has USSD support too.
- Can manage (Stop or Start) the processes that use bandwidth.

For a complete list of features, visit the [official homepage](https://linuxonly.ru/page/modem-manager-gui). It is available on Ubuntu repos for **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** and above. To install, click here:

[image: Modem Manager GUI App on Ubuntu Software]

Or run the following command:

```
sudo apt install modem-manager-gui
```

[image: Modem Manager GUI]

Comment: How to use this to connect??

Answer (score 3):

## V Mobile Broadband

**V Mobile Broadband** is the original **Vodafone Mobile Connect** software for Linux rewritten to be compatible with Network Manager. Vodafone is a distributer of Huawei USB modems. **V Mobile Broadband** is developed by Vodafone's open source [Betavine Connection Manager](https://forge.betavine.net/projects/bcm) team. For the latest developments, check out their [Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecrass/+archive/v-mobile-broadband) and [GitHub Page](https://github.com/andrewbird/vodafone-mobile-broadband)

V-Mobile-Broadband is mentioned as having these functionalities:
⠀• Connection & Disconnection
⠀• SMS
⠀• Display Bandwidth
⠀• Display Data Usage

Unfortunately, V Mobile Broadband is not available in Ubuntu Software Center yet. You'll have to install it from PPA. To add the PPA, run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crass/v-mobile-broadband
sudo apt-get update
```

After successfully adding the PPA, click here to install [v-mobile-broadband](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/v-mobile-broadband) [image: Install v-mobile-broadband]
Or, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install v-mobile-broadband
```

**Warning**: `v-mobile-broadband` depends on `wader`, which replaces Ubuntu's default `modemmanager`. So, if you encounter any problem with the new setup and decide to uninstall `v-mobile-broadband`, don't forget to reinstall `modemmanager` package.

[image: V Mobile Broadband]