# Download Ubuntu packages

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to download http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/v-mobile-broadband from firefox on Ubuntu 14.04, but it give me a prompt that says choose the application to open the downloaded file, so I don't know what I should choose and why when installing other things from other websites it start download normally?

Comment: choose software-center from `/usr/bin`

Comment: I choose it but it give me : 'There isn’t a software package called “v-mobile-broadband” in your current software sources'

Comment: v-mobile-broadband has been removed from 14.04. It is the reason. Try with the Launchpad repository given you earlier.

Comment: Visit [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/380650/in-ubuntu-is-there-an-application-like-huawei-mobile-partner-for-broadband-co) for installing such app. Alternatively install `modem-manager-gui` by [apt-link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modem-manager-gui/)

Answer (score 1):

V Mobile Broadband is not in default Ubuntu Software Center repositary currenlty. You will have to install it from PPA. To add the PPA, run next commands in console:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:crass/v-mobile-broadband
sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get install v-mobile-broadband
```

or open your link above with `software-center` from `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/7622110/

Comment: it must be here `http://ppa.launchpad.net/crass/v-mobile-broadband/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages`  not in  `http://ppa.launchpad.net/crass/v-mobile-broadband/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages` so it is `trusty` not `saucy`, thinking how add/fix it.