# Help me with installing modem driver software

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb-modem, 3g

I am having Huawei ec 150 Data card. It works well with the default network programs in Ubuntu. My network provider offers 3g speed upto 1gb for two days There after the speed will drops as per the plan. The problem is that the default program in ubuntu works for 3g speed. when i cross the 1gb data limit i cant able to access the network not signal is being detected. So i have to install [driver software](http://www.reliancenetconnect.co.in/others/Huawei%20New%20Dialer%20-%206085%20New%20Chipset.zip) for the device. I tried so many ways and installed finally. However the software doesn't detect the network. So kindly provide me the details how should i configure my device.

```
xxx@xxx:~$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 12d1:140b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. Media Keyboard K200
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

If any other set of details needed kindly comment.
[image]

Comment: follow this question and install applications : http://askubuntu.com/q/380650/308564

Comment: I have tried those things before. All i need is that i have to get signals from the device driver software which i have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the software and extract it to the desktop.

Then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Type `sudo -s` and enter your password. After that, type:

```
cd /home/umar/Desktop/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Huawei New Dialer - 6085 New Chipset/Linux
bash install_linux
```

The program gets installed.

Comment: I've edited this so it will work as given, without requiring modifications. (A detailed explanation for the changes I've made is in the edit history.) But please feel free to roll back or edit again, if you don't like the current version or otherwise want to change/improve it further.